# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type in react project

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a react project. when I want to use react-leaflet I get this error:

```
./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/VideoOverlay.js 10:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   var overlay = new LeafletVideoOverlay(url, bounds, options);
|   if (options.play === true) {
>     overlay.getElement()?.play();
|   }
|   return createElementObject(overlay, extendContext(ctx, {
```

I did just like document in my component. I installed with npm, and ...

note: leaflet and react-leaflet are installed. I'm using react "^18.2.0", leaflet "^1.9.2" and react leaflet "^4.1.0" in my project
project info:

My code in this component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'

const DestinationFormAdd = (props) =>{

const position = [51.505, -0.09]


return(

<div>
    <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
    </MapContainer>
</div>
)
```

}